# Use keyof to extract a string literal union of only keys that have values of a specific type

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types, mapped-types

For example, how can we extract only the keys that have string types? [Here is what I have tried:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=81#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwKLIYiBnA8sgDYgA8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBQtQDaA0lClANYQgA9gDMo5ALoAuMZ3FQIAD2ARkAE1xRc2NFAD8MjnOnIIANwjwA3IwC%20jRqEixBAWwjlw0Ok1ZQAhnBIaNJaQajWvn4AcgCuLgBGFsZxiVa29gDGgshaUKYAjNKBKBhYSHiEJKQwru6e1N7MrAHaqNIA5AASEEREgu0ANE0s0SlJUPkADANQAPSzYgAWiBor-lBZLmCIRBby8PCC8AB0UADigoKqp%20kOnrCtHAIadPxCosVomNgVxGQ1bg8kEo1kYWRywDyACYio9nrQoO1RgkLO1LHMFp1BAB3DZ%20ZBQbHQFx%20fhQYCLaCbba7eAbVxgIh%20HiU%20AQXRAA)

```
type StringEntriesOnly<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never;
}

type SomeType = {
    aString: string;
    aNumber: number;
}

const v1: StringEntriesOnly<SomeType> = {
    aString: 'Hello',
    aNumber: 10, // This is a compiler error. Good. 
}

type StringKeys = keyof StringEntriesOnly<SomeType>;

const v2: StringKeys = 'aNumber'; // How can we make the compiler complain here?
```

In the above example, I would like `StringKeys` to allow only 'aString'.

Comment: 'tis indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually define `KeysMatching` like this

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

(the `-?` avoids some pitfalls with optional properties while introducing other pitfalls; check edge cases)

That gives you

```
type StringKeys = KeysMatching<SomeType, string>;
// type StringKeys = "aString"

const v2: StringKeys = 'aNumber'; // error!
```

Hope it helps.  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvKAbRijygGt4B7AMyjEAugFoA-AC5BrIVAgAPYBFwATBJShjYUKbggA3CACcoAX2bcQ-QUIDcAKHuhIUAMo8AthGLho9BvZQQVAorsBGePhSCOGRDsEhAHIArh4ARsa6qRlGDqaOztBhEQRwiHSw8MhoWJGE7l4+kOQxJfhUDgD0nVCFbrGlVRUARKED+MOO6Dy4MVD6AExSxZFl6vQA5Cgp6cYbtlDdckZGPEYAhFBAA)

Comment: Why bother with the `-?`? `KeysMatching` works without that.

Comment: If your `SomeType` has optional properties you can get weirdness without it.  Try making `aNumber` optional and see what happens.  The `undefined` bleeds out into the answer.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvKAbRijygGt4B7AMyjEAugC5BrIVAgAPYBFwATBJSgB+WFDG4IANwgAnKAF9m3EP0FCA3ACgboSFADKPALYRi4aPQY2o-qBQnYH08fDEEELDbAMCAOQBXVwAjA1UtJNT9WyM7B2hg0II4RDpYeGQ0LDDCF3dPSHJIovwqWwB6dqh85yjiirKAIiC+-EGoAB8oBMUIPjwIBSgAQlVluyA)